# Set a DynamicResource reference to pick an individual element from a list in the resources

Tags: wpf

**Basic Question**

What I am trying (and failing) to do is pretty simple conceptually.  I have an ArrayList of brushes as a resource, and I would like to bind an individual element's color to an element at a specific index in the ArrayList.  If possible, I would like to get the index to bind to from the element's datacontext.

What it would look like is something like this:

```
<Line Stroke={DynamicResource DefaultGraphBrushes[0]}/>
```

I have tried a number of permutations of this (explicitly setting the ResourceKey, using quotes, '.', etc), and I am hardcoding the index for now to see if I can even do this.  I would ideally like to get the index from the datacontext of the line.

**Context**

I am trying to do this because I have a graph control that takes in an arbitrary number of data sets and plots them on a grid.  Some of the data sets have colors defined in the view model that they should always be shown in, some do not.  For the ones that do I am simply binding to the color they provide and that works fine.  For the ones that do not I need to pick a unique color from a predefined list of colors.  The application has several different "themes" available, and the list of colors to use for the graph is different for each theme in order to make it readable and pretty.  The brush the line is using needs to update when the user changes themes.

In the view model for each data set it knows whether it has an assigned color or not, and if it does not it picks the next index in the list of predefined colors to use to prevent multiple data sets from using the same color (unless we have more data sets than colors, which is unlikely).

I have been searching for a way to do this for quite a while.  Any suggestions on how to make this approach work, or on other approaches that may work better are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This is harder than you'd think...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been realizing.  It seemed like such a simple thing when I was first thinking about the behavior, but trying to implement it has me running in circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes i don't understand why one should try too long to find a Xaml solution if this can be done much easier in code... Why not Bind your Stroke to a property that computes the Color ? code might access as well to resources (with TryfindResource or SetResourceReference). if you use tryfindresource, NotifyPropertyChanged if resource changed.

Comment: My code that sets the index and/or color is in the viewmodel.  I don't have access to SetResourceReference there, since that function exists on FrameworkElements, which are in the visual tree, not the viewmodel.  I tried loading the resource in the viewmodel and grabbing the color and exposing it as a property, but then I get the static color from the current theme and if they change themes that color won't change with everything else.

Comment: have your app raise a "ThemeChanged" event, and handle it.

Comment: There isn't a good way to hook that event unless there is some way to broadcast an event to the entire visual tree. The main window of the application where the themes get changed can hold one of a number of different "layouts" with vastly different content. I can't do a direct event hook since the graph could be buried way down in the visual tree anywhere in any layout. The main window has no idea where it is or if it exists, and the graph doesn't know what is above it. Forcing a direct connection there seems like a nightmare to maintain, and the type of thing WPF typically solves nicely.

Comment: Ended up putting a static event for theme changes in an existing helper class in the same assembly as the viewmodels so it is accessible from the places that need it without causing circular dependencies.  The ViewModels assembly is referenced from pretty much everywhere.

Comment: yes that what i meant : a static event to which you can add an handler anywhere in your application without doing " hugly" things. glad i could help